# How to calculate percentages in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate a percentage for the number of successful applications grouped by State.

I'm using mySQL and I can run a query to obtain a list of states with the number of total applications and successful applications. I am not sure how to combine the two queries and then try and calculate a percentage value. I'm assuming I have to run a subquery of some kind here, but not too sure.

```
SELECT w.state, c.case_status, COUNT(w.state) AS No_Applications
FROM worksites w JOIN cases c USING (WorksiteID)
WHERE c.Case_Status like '%certified%'
GROUP BY w.state
ORDER BY w.state ASC;

SELECT w.state, COUNT(w.state) AS No_Total_Applications
FROM worksites w JOIN cases c USING (WorksiteID)
GROUP BY w.state
ORDER BY w.state ASC;

SELECT w.state, c.case_status, COUNT(w.state FROM worksites w JOIN cases c WHERE c.Case_Status like '%certified%') AS Success_Applications,
COUNT (w.state) AS Total_Applications
FROM worksites w JOIN cases c USING (WorksiteID)
GROUP BY w.state
ORDER BY No_Applications ASC;
```

The first two codes return the number of successful and total applications respectively; the third code was my attempt and merging the two -- it failed saying "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM worksites w JOIN cases c WHERE c.Case_Status like '%certified%') AS Success' at line 1"

Comment: Probably a good idea to learn how to use `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you can simply do:

```
SELECT w.state, 
       SUM(c.Case_Status like '%certified%') AS No_Applications
       AVG(c.Case_Status like '%certified%') as ratio
FROM worksites w JOIN
     cases c
     USING (WorksiteID)
GROUP BY w.state
ORDER BY w.state ASC;
```

MySQL treats booleans as numbers in a numeric context, simplifying the arithmetic using them.

Also note that I removed `Case_Status` from the `SELECT`.  It is not part of the `GROUP BY`, so it is not really appropriate (and there will be multiple values for each `w.state`).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join 2 queries together, you can just extend your query so that it count number of certified without filtering the whole table

```
SELECT 
  w.state, 
  c.case_status, 
  COUNT(w.state) AS No_Total_Applications,
  SUM(CASE WHEN c.Case_Status like '%certified%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS No_Applications,
  SUM(CASE WHEN c.Case_Status like '%certified%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(w.state) AS Percentage
FROM worksites w JOIN cases c USING (WorksiteID)
GROUP BY w.state
ORDER BY w.state ASC;
```

Comment: Got the following error: 
"Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS No_Applications,   SUM(CASE WHEN c.Case_Status like '%certified%' THEN 1 EL' at line 4"

Comment: Hello. Sorry forgotten the "END" clause at the end. Added above.